# Is there a way to change the double-press speed on the Apple headphones?

Tags: iphone, headphones

Specifically, I have the newest headphones which were released with the iPhone5, however if you have an answer for any of the headphones they released, this may be a good place to centralize the information.

I've found I'm constantly not double-pressing fast enough to cause the phone to go to the next track while listening to music, not to mention if I want to go back (three-presses). I would love to be able to increase the allowed delay between presses so I don't constantly pause/un-pause my music instead of going to the next song.

Comment: This has often bothered me as well. Alas, I doubt there's a solution short of, um, rewiring or replacing the switch, somehow. :S

Comment: Takes some exercise to get it right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.I have non-Apple earphones with a mini remote with three buttons - the central one being the one to be double-pressed. I have turned the Internet upside down and haven't found anything close to this, even on jailbreak (my ipod touch is jailbroken).

Comment: This is mostly likely because the software only receives one of a set of discrete signals from the headphones: "Single Click", "Double Click", "Triple Click", "Volume Down Clicked", etc. Changing *which signal is generated* when you press the button at a certain speed would require changing the electronics in the headphone remote itself.

Comment: Well, the other option is that there is one signal - "Clicked" - and the software manages determining single/double/triple. This is how it works with a standard Mouse as far as I'm aware. Granted, like @Stephan, it looks like it is all implemented in hardware.